# (JavaScript) Minimum number needed to add each number in an array such that it will never go below one

Tags: javascript, arrays

The easiest way to explain this is with the text from the example problem:

> Each element inside the battlefield array indicates the enemy's power. The negative power decreases your power and positive power boosts your power. The task is to return what is the minimum power you carry in the beginning of battle to successfully pass the battle field. At any stage if your power becomes zero (or less), you die.

And this is what I tried:

```
    function findPower() {
      var enemyPower = 0;
      var battlefield = [-5, 7, 0, 5, 3, 9, -2, -8, 4, 3, -8];          

      for(var i = 0; battlefield.length; i++) {
        enemyPower = (battlefield[i] < 0 ? (enemyPower + battlefield[i]) : enemyPower);
      }

    enemyPower = (enemyPower <0) ? (-1 * enemyPower + 1) : 1;

    return enemyPower;;
    }
```

The `battlefield` array is just a test array, and this should return 6. If you remove the -5 so that it's `[7, 0, 5, 3, 9, -2, -8, 4, 3, -8]` it should be 1 (because you can't start with 0 power). I feel as if I'm just returning the wrong value or something but whenever I start writing conditionals it just doesn't feel right.

This problem is for an interview practice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `1 - Math.min(...battlefield.reduce((a, b) => [...a, a.slice(-1)[0] + b], [0]));`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go through the `battlefield` initially, simulating if you had entered with 0 power, adding and subtracting as required, keeping track of the lowest power you reach. The difference between that lowest number and 1 is the power you need to start with:

```js
function findPower() {
  let power = 0;
  let lowestPower = 0;
  const battlefield = [-5, 7, 0, 5, 3, 9, -2, -8, 4, 3, -8];
  battlefield.forEach((num) => {
    power += num;
    lowestPower = Math.min(lowestPower, power);
  });
  return 1 - lowestPower;
}

console.log(findPower());
```

Note that even if the `battlefield` doesn't contain any negative numbers, `lowestPower` will still be 0 at the end, which means that 1 will be returned (which makes sense, because you need at least 1 power all the time, including before iterating through the array).